# Сумма элементов массива с заданным значением

Tags: c++

Прошу помочь решить данную задачку с помощью обычного `for`.

Моя версия:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
   int i; 
   int sum; 
   int mas[i] = {1,1,1,1}; 
   for (i=0; i<4; i++) { sum+=i; } 
   cout << sum; 
}
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду, говоря о заданных значениях?  Заданы значения массива или заданы определенные элементы, сумму которых нужно считать? В любом случаи сумма изначально должна иметь нулевое значение

Answer (score 1):

Тут крайне не любят вопросы, где автор даже не попытался написать свой код на эту тему, не приложив свои попытки и четко не описав, что именно он не понимает. Но все же поможем вам:)

```
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    if (mas[i] == tmp) sum += mas[i];
}
```

`N` - длинна массива.

`tmp` - заданное значение.

`sum` - переменная, куда мы записываем сумму элементов.

p.s. постарайтесь больше не задавать так вопросы.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    int sum;
    int mas[i] = {1,1,1,1};
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        sum+=i;
    }
    cout << sum;
}
 У меня был код) стыдно показывать

Comment: Своим кодом вы считаете сумму индексов элементов массива, не проводя даже проверку на значение:)

Comment: @МаксимРусских, не стесняйтесь. В этом нет ничего зазорного. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте туда этот код.

Answer (score 0):

Готовый код:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{
int i, sum, mas[4] = {1,1,1,1}; 
sum=0;
for (i=0; i<4; i++) sum+=i;  
cout << sum; 
return 0;
}
```

Такс, а теперь объяснение:
Массив 4 потому что есть данные числа и определённое их количество;
Можно переменные задавать в одну строку;
`sum=0;` -должно быть начальное значение (если умножение тогда равно 1);
Цикл фор всегда после себя исполняет одну операцию (а вы ради этого использовали ещё одну под программу так сказать);

```
return 0;
```

так сказать корректный выход из программы `int main(){... return 0;}` 
ещё иногда его не хватает и есть оператор`system("pause");` он ставится перед `return 0;`.

Comment: Извините за калиграфию, я старался подать материал, а не розставить комы в нужном месте или убрать несколько 'не' потому что в одном предложении нельзя несколько 'нет' и т.д. но суть подана.